# Removing a file from TortoiseHG data source

Tags: file, version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHG for source code control in Windows, I forgot to edit the ".hgignor" file, and now I have a huge folder ".hg" which I know it's because of DLL and EXE and PDB files which I do not need them. Now changing the ignor file does not remove those files.

What should I do for deleting these files completely from my TortoiseHg data source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `hg remove` command to remove files in your repository.  If you are using TortoiseHG, you can right click on the file and go: TortoiseHG -> Remove File.

Check out the "How to stop tracking a file" section [Here.](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html)

Comment: Thanks very much. this command also deletes the file from hard drive, what should I do if I want to keep them?

Answer (score 7):

if you want to stop tracking files, but leave them in working directory, use `hg forget`. Help also says you can achieve the same effect by using `hg remove -Af`.

I'm not sure what do you mean by «data source», but neither of those will remove the files from repository itself, because they are already a part of your history, and thus their previous versions will remain there. Forgetting them will only prevent your history from bloating even further with newer versions of those build artifacts.